# In a Liferay theme, what is the difference between 'clay/base' and 'clay/atlas'

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-theme

I am starting to develop Liferay themes and the documentation seems to show that you should import 'clay/atlas'.

I have an import for 'clay/base' instead:

```
@import 'clay/base';
```

Can someone shed some light on what the difference is and why I would use one instead of the other?

I saw this question [How to implement Clay in Liferay 7.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58804524/17128918), but it didn't help (in fact it confused me more).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in deeper I think I've figured it out.

Both are what Liferay calls "sub-themes".

clay/base is the "Base" sub-theme, which is the base implementation of Clay.  Clay is an extension of Bootstrap, and implements Liferay's Lexicon design language.

clay/atlas is the "Atlas" sub-theme, which is an enhancement of Clay and Bootstrap to provide the equivalent of a Bootstrap theme and is used to produce the look and feel of the "Classic" Liferay theme.

This is a summary of various pieces of information found in the Liferay documentation.